# How to validate form when ng-click in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

Any ideas on how I can make the html/browser validation work in the below code when also having to call a method. Also I can't use the submit type as a method because it's being used somewhere else. I need an alternative for the ng-click I suppose.

```
<input type="submit" ng-click="vm.submit1()" class="submitBtn" />
```

[image]

I guess I only want the ng-click to work only if the ng-submit has validated the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside submit1 function, could you check **form.$valid** ?

```
<input type="button" ng-click="vm.submit1(form)" class="submitBtn" />

function YourController() {

   var self = this;
   self.submit1 = function(form) {
      if (form.$valid) { // OR self.form.$valid
         ...
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was after

Answer (score 0):

use it on button with the form name it will keep the button disabled until the form data will validated.

```
ng-disabled="frmLogin.$invalid"
```

here is the full code for normal login form for your help

```
<form  novalidate name="frmLogin" id="frmLogin" ng-submit="vm.doLogin()">

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="txtusername" id="txtusername" ng-model="vm.newLogin.username"  required/>
                <span class="text-danger" ng-show="frmLogin.txtusername.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword" ng-model="vm.newLogin.password" required/>
                <span class="text-danger" ng-show="frmLogin.txtpassword.$error.required">Password is required.</span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="frmLogin.$invalid">Login</button>

            </div>
            <div>
                Don't have a Account? <a href="#/Register"><strong>Register Now</strong></a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: No the thing is that I want to show the browsers validation like the image and not my own validation only. My own is working thank you kind sir :)

Comment: then try using required at element tag like <input class="form-control" type="password" name="txtpassword" id="txtpassword" required/>

Comment: Yes I also have that and still whenever I click on the button only the method is being thrown and the browsers validation no longer works